# How can I get in what rank the user is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these as models and column.

- Users(Table)
- UserProfiles(Table)

  - total_point(column)

I want to display the rank of the user in an array when it's sorted by associated table column called `total_point`

So I tried this but it gave error back.

How can I solve this?

**application_helper** (passing user as an argument)

```
def user_rank(user)   
    "<i><b>#{user.user_profile.total_point}#{User.confirmed.joins(:user_profile).order('user_profiles.total_point DESC').index(user)}</b></i>".html_safe
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
scope :confirmed, where("confirmation_token" => nil)
has_one: user_profile
```

UPDATE:

**models/user_profile.rb**

```
belongs_to: user
```

**ERROR**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
29:  <td class="border"> <%= user_rank(@user) %></td>
```

Comment: you should post your models and the error you get.

Comment: not really sure what the error points to. can you add a space between `total_point` and `DESC`? or is that just a typo?

Comment: @jvnill Thanks. It was my mistake just typo. But it still gets the same error:( I have no idea what to do with it

Comment: I can't see the error yet, but I recommend pulling bits out of the logic until the error goes away - that way you'll know which piece of the code is causing it. So, does it work (or at least not produce the error) if you don't use the `confirmed` scope? Does it work if you don't call `.index` on the result? And so on.